# HTML, Moving Problem of Bar and Footer Sections

Tags: html, css

I had 2 questions. These are like as below:
First, How can I move the animation of the moving bar (blue colored) above the border at the top? Second, How can I move text (get in touch with me) and logos (LinkedIn and StackOverflow) centered to the bottom of the page? I have added some descriptions to the image.

[image: intended effect]

The code:

```css
.headerStyle {
  border-color: black;
}
body {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 5s;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.Loading {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loading:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  animation: load 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }

  25% {
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }

  50% {
    width: 10%;
    left: 90%;
  }

  75% {
    width: 50%;
    left: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 10%;
    left: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }

  25% {
    border-color: orange;
  }

  50% {
    border-color: brown;
  }

  75% {
    border-color: #d94d5f;
  }

  100% {
    border-color: #ffcccb;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="headerStyle"><b>Get In Touch With Me</b></p>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img class="image1" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/2111/2111628.png" alt="stackoverflow icon" width="60" height="60"></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><img class="image2" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png" alt="linkedin icon" width="60" height="60">
    </a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="Loading"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please focus your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "moving the loading bar above the border", I am assuming that you want the loading bar instead of the top border!

You can set the `border-top: none` for the body tag and move the `loading` div to the top most part.

For centering  the text you can use text-align and for the images use the flex property.

```html
<html>
<html>
<style>
    .headerStyle {
        border-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 85vh;
    }

    .flex-box {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    body {
        border-style: solid;
        border-top: none;
        border-width: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        transition: 5s;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        animation: pulse 5s infinite;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 0px 0px;
    }

    .Loading {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10px;
        background: #f1f1f1;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        border-radius: 4px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .Loading:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background: blue;
        width: 10%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        animation: load 5s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes load {
        0% {
            left: 0%;

        }

        25% {
            width: 50%;
            left: 50%
        }

        50% {
            width: 10%;
            left: 90%
        }

        75% {
            width: 50%;
            left: 0%
        }

        100% {
            width: 10%;
            left: 0%
        }
    }

    @keyframes pulse {
        0% {
            border-color: red;
        }

        25% {
            border-color: orange;
        }

        50% {
            border-color: brown;
        }

        75% {
            border-color: #d94d5f;
        }

        100% {
            border-color: #ffcccb;
        }
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="Loading"></div>
        </div>


        <p class="headerStyle"><b>Get In Touch With Me</b></p>

        <div class="flex-box">
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img class="image1"
                    src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/2111/2111628.png" alt="stackoverflow icon" width="60"
                    height="60"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><img class="image2"
                    src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png" alt="linkedin icon" width="60"
                    height="60">
            </a>
        </div>


    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Texts and logos are centered but still not visible at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @murattaşçı Do you want them placed at the bottom with empty space between the loading bar and text?

Comment: Yes if it is possible, like the picture I added to the issue. I want an empty area Between the Loading bar and the footer section.

Comment: @murattaşçı you can try margin-top for .headerStyle to create empty space. I have made changes to the code

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<style>

.headerStyle{

border-color: black;


}
body {
  border-style: solid;
  
  border-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 5s;

}


body {
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
}

.container {

  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto; 
  padding: 0px 0px;

}

.Loading {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loading:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  animation: load 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
 
  }
  
  25% {
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%

  }
  
  50% {
    width: 10%;
    left: 90%

  }
  
  75% {
    width: 50%;
    left: 0%

  }
  
  100% {
    width: 10%;
    left: 0%
 
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
        border-color: red;
  }
  
  25% {
        border-color: orange;
  }
  
  50% {
        border-color: brown;
  }
  
  75% {
        border-color: #d94d5f;
  }
  
  100% {
        border-color: #ffcccb;
  }
}

</style>
<body>
<div class="footer" style="
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100vh;
">
        <p class="headerStyle"><b>Get In Touch With Me</b></p>
        <div>        <div style="
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
">

        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img class="image1" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/2111/2111628.png"
                alt="stackoverflow icon" width="60" height="60"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><img class="image2" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png"
                alt="linkedin icon" width="60" height="60">
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    <div class="Loading"></div>
  </div>
        
</div>

  

</body>
</html>
```

1. `.footer` set

   - `display: flex;` is use to set flexbox.
   - `flex-direction: Column;` is use to set flexbox direction.
   - `justify-content: space-between` is use to set space between items.
2. `.footer` inside logos and bottom bar set on div
3. `logos > div` set `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` set logos in center.

Comment: Please answer the question and not just provide code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - Please also explain your edit, and not just provide the code and "| use flexbox".

Comment: @ethry check out edited answer bro!

Answer (score 0):

Here I changed some corruption in your code hope you can find the solution.

You can check in this code here:

```
.headerStyle {
    border-color: black;
}

body {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 5s;
}

body {
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
}

.container {

  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto; 
  padding: 0px 0px;
  height: 100vh;

}

.Loading {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loading:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  animation: load 5s infinite;
}

        
        @keyframes load {
          0% {
            left: 0%;
         
          }
          
          25% {
            width: 50%;
            left: 50%
        
          }
          
          50% {
            width: 10%;
            left: 90%
        
          }
          
          75% {
            width: 50%;
            left: 0%
        
          }
          
          100% {
            width: 10%;
            left: 0%
         
          }
        }
        
        @keyframes pulse {
          0% {
                border-color: red;
          }
          
          25% {
                border-color: orange;
          }
          
          50% {
                border-color: brown;
          }
          
          75% {
                border-color: #d94d5f;
          }
          
          100% {
                border-color: #ffcccb;
          }
        }
    .footer .contact-us {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        
        </style>


<body>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="contact-us">
        <p class="headerStyle"><b>Get In Touch With Me</b></p>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img class="image1" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/2111/2111628.png"
                alt="stackoverflow icon" width="60" height="60"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><img class="image2" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png"
                alt="linkedin icon" width="60" height="60">
        </a>
    </div>
        <div class="container">
    <div class="Loading"></div>
  </div>
        
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please fix your formatting and explain your code.